# Left Join based on condition

Tags: join, mybatis

```
  <sql id="users">
    SELECT * FROM TBLUSERS user
    LEFT JOIN TBLUSERCOUNTRY1 user_c1 on user_c1.code = user.value
    LEFT JOIN TBLUSERCOUNTRY2 user_c2 on user_c2.id = user.value
  </sql>
```

the TBLUSERCOUNTRY1 has columns countryCode, country
the TBLUSERCOUNTRY2 has columns countryId, country

user.value can either be 'US' or 1, if it is US, the first LEFT JOIN will return results, if it is 1, the 2nd one will return results

so I basically want to run the first join, if user.value is a string and 2nd one if user.value is an int

Running it the way it is throws an integer error

Answer (score 0):

adding `TO_CHAR` fixed it

```
  <sql id="users">
    SELECT * FROM TBLUSERS user
    LEFT JOIN TBLUSERCOUNTRY1 user_c1 on user_c1.code = user.value
    LEFT JOIN TBLUSERCOUNTRY2 user_c2 on TO_CHAR(user_c2.id) = user.value
  </sql>
```